# Graphics2D won't fill a path

Tags: java, path, fill, graphics2d

I'm making a game and I want to draw mountains myself. I make the mountains using mid point displacement, store the points in an arraylist and then retrieve them in my Jpanel in my view. I draw other stuff like grass and g2 will fill them with colors but not my mountain. Here is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zhUP.png

Here's the code:

```
Point2D.Double start = new Point2D.Double(50, 400);
listePoints.add(start);

Point2D.Double end = new Point2D.Double(modele.getLargeur(), 400);
listePoints.add(end);       
this.maxIterations = 9;
int iterations = 0;
int minHeight = 5;
double nbrRandom = 10;
    while(iterations <  this.maxIterations) {
        iterations ++;
        int counter = 0;
        int size = listePoints.size()-1;
        int index = 0;
        while (compteur < size) {

            Point2D.Double point1 = listePoints.get(index);
            Point2D.Double point2 = listePoints.get(index+1);
            double milieu = Math.abs(point2.x - point1.x)/2;

            int orientation = Equations.randInt(1);
            switch(orientation ) {
            case 0: orientation  = -1;break;
            case 1: orientation  = 1;break;
            }


            Point2D.Double point3 = new Point2D.Double(point1.x+milieu,point1.y+(Equations.rand((nbrRandom+iterations = 0;
int minHeight)*orientation)));
            nbrRandom = nbrRandom /2;

            listePoints.add(index+1,point3);
            index +=2;
            counter++ ;
    }       

    }
    Point2D.Double point1 = new Point2D.Double(start.x,500);

    listePoints.add(0,point1);

    point1 = new Point2D.Double(end.x,500);

    listePoints.add(listePoints.size(),point1);

    point1 = new Point2D.Double(start.x,500);

    listePoints.add(listePoints.size(),point1);

/***************************** VIEW **/


        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double(Path2D.Double.WIND_EVEN_ODD);    
        for (int j = 0;j < list.size()-1; j++) {


            Point2D.Double point1 = list.get(j);    
            Point2D.Double point2 =list.get(j+1);   


            path.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
            path.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);

            path.closePath();
            g2.draw(path);
            g2.fill(path);
        }               
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Did you have a question?

Comment: I went to edit the post to in-line the screen-shot, but chose not to in-line that one.  It is a not very clear, and large in pixels representation of a simple problem.  3) For making great screen-shots, see the tips on [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).  The most important tips are a) Small! b) White BG.  In addition to those tips, don't resize images prior to uploading.  Resizing will generally make images *larger* in bytes, but less clear and precise.

Comment: *"don't resize images"*  (silly grin)  Ignore that comment - that was my browser doing the resizing (from an enormous 1632x1224).

Answer (score 2):

If the question is "How do I fill the area below the jagged line with color?", the answer is:

1. Join the end (presumably the right-hand side of the `ArrayList` of points) to the bottom of the container on the RHS.
2. Join that point to the bottom LHS.
3. Then call `path.closePath();`

Or to put that another way, join the path end to the path start via the 'ground'.

If this explanation does not solve the problem for you (or if I guessed the question wrong), post an SSCCE.

Comment: Yes that is my question! I know it's kind of complicated to dissect that code, I have to use MVC for the project so my model is separated from the view. Anyway the path.closePath() doesn't work. I guess my question in general is what makes the fill method not work on a path.

Comment: After debugging a bit, I'm pretty sure there must be TINY :P holes in the path, that's why it doesn't fill. I think that is a condition for fill to work properly, right?

Comment: If you want more help from me, post an SSCCE.